# Kubernetes pods are only working when deployed on 2 of 4 nodes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, ubuntu-20.04

I have a cluster of 4 Raspberry Pis running ubuntu 20.04 that I have installed Microk8s and created a Kubernetes cluster on. I seem to be having some networking issues when deploying pods on 2 of the 4 nodes.

I created a Daemon Set of Nginx pods, and if I `exec` into the pods on Node-01 or Node-04 and run `apt update` I get:

```
root@nginx-deployment-wh72m:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease        
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
31 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

However if I run the same command in the pods on Node-02 or Node-03 I get:

```
root@nginx-deployment-bd9kn:/# apt update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

All of the nodes were installed using the same process. I am also able to run `apt update` on all the nodes themselves.

Comment: Sounds like container networking on those nodes is broken. Run a utility pod and see if that works.

Comment: @coderanger is there a specific utility pod that would work best that you know of?

Comment: I usually just use `ubuntu:latest` but everyone has a favorite.

Comment: what addons you enabled in mikrok8s? Im not sure, this is assumption. I see that [dns addon](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dns) `deploys CoreDNS to supply address resolution services to Kubernetes.`